# Batch File to Prompt user for input then execute another bat file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to setup a bat file that asks the user to choose option 1 or option 2.  then create two other bat files to run when either of the input is selected.

So the initial bat file will ask the user to select what Theater

1) Theater 1
2) Theater 2

then the bat file to run the associated bat with the choice select

theater1.bat or theater2.bat

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set /p option=Enter either option 1 or option 2 (1/2):
if %option%==1 (
call theater1.bat
) else (
if %option%==2 (
call theater2.bat
) else (
echo Invalid option entered
)
)
pause >nul
```